# multilog compatibility wrapper for svlogd?

Tags: daemontools

Has anyone written a compatibility wrapper for `svlogd` to function as a drop-in replacement for `multilog`?

I'm a fan of UNIX process supervision in the style of [`daemontools`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html) and lately of [`runit`](http://smarden.org/runit/).  While `runit` offers a compatibility mode for many of the `daemontools` utilities, there is AFAIK no such offering for `svlogd`.  I've got a few systems I'd like to switch over to `runit`, but I'd rather not modify the `.../log/run` scripts of every supervised process on those machines.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder, has anyone ever tried to write a master script for all of the `log/run` instances and then simply symlinked it?  This would allow you to shuffle between logging setups without touching 30 bazillion scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, [`runit-dt`](http://cmrg.fifthhorseman.net/browser/trunk/runit-dt) provides a `multilog` wrapper that is the closest thing I've found.

It does what I naively think covers 90% of `multilog` uses:  translate 'multilog t ...' to 'svlogd -t ...', and nothing more.